# how to install certificate in Trsusted Credentials\User

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I have client certificate(.pfx or .p12) which is signed from a local CA (Organization) and upon installing it on Android device 9(Pie)(MI A2), the certificate goes and sits in the "**Settings\Security & location\Advanced\Encryption & credentials\User credentials**" but my expectation is that is should go and sit in "**Settings\Security & location\Advanced\Encryption & credentials\Trusted credentials\User**"

I have googled a lot but I did not find any convincing solution about how to install certificate  "**Settings\Security & location\Advanced\Encryption & credentials\Trusted credentials\User**"

Any help regarding this would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Vinod